# FileLoad Exception when attempting to alter IIS site configurations through powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, web-administration

I'm trying to set up an installation PS script to handle the installation and configuration of two application pools/sites. The creation is handled correctly, and it adjusts the 32-bit applications property fine, but I hit the following error once I try to enable parent paths:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This
> happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default
> (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or
> the legacy allowOverride="false".

My code is below - assume all variables are initialized elsewhere. I've tried adding a -Location specification, to no avail. I've also tried changing the applicationHost.config settings to 'Allow' on the module front.

```
New-WebAppPool app1
New-WebAppPool app2 

#Creates a new webapplication under Default Web Sites
New-WebApplication -Name app1 -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath $srcPath -ApplicationPool app1 
New-WebApplication -Name app2 -Site 'Default Web Site' -PhysicalPath $MCCPath -ApplicationPool app2 #ALT ID:001

Set-Location IIS:\;

#Sets app1's app pool to enable 32 bit.
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\app1 -Name enable32BitAppOnWin64 -Value true #ALT ID:001

#Sets ASP enable parent path to true (THIS is where it throws the error)
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\app1'  -Filter system.webServer/asp -Name enableParentPaths -Value $true #ALT ID:001
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\app2'  -Filter system.webServer/asp -Name enableParentPaths -Value $true #ALT ID:001
    
#Sets AnonymousAuthentication to use app pool identity
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\app1' -Filter System.WebServer/Security/Authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -Name username -Value "" -Location MyLocation #ALT ID:001
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\app2' -Filter System.WebServer/Security/Authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -Name username -Value "" -Location MyLocation #ALT ID:001

#Sets Windows AD user as pass thru within app pools
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\app1 -Name processModel -Value @{userName = "$usrName";password="$usrPswd";identitytype=3} #ALT ID:001
Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\app2 -Name processModel -Value @{userName = "$usrName";password="$usrPswd";identitytype=3} #ALT ID:001
```

Edit: Got it. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config, there is a config file titled 'applicationHost.config'. Within that, the .asp section's overrideModeDefault needs to be changed from "Deny" to "Allow". This resolved the issue.

Now I just have to figure out how to get powershell to make THAT change.
Changing the command to

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST -Location 'Default Web Site/app2' -Filter System.WebServer/Security/Authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -Name username -Value ""  #ALT ID:001
```

also did the trick.